# Inner join between OLTP and Reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to have inner join between OLTP and reporting tables.

```
select * from tbltable(nolock) a 
inner join [report].[schema].[tbltablename](nolock) b on b.c1=a.c1
```

This is returning an error.

Why is it so?

Comment: Don't be shy.  What error?

Comment: 'Remote-table-valued-function-calls-are-not-allowed' @GordonLinoff

Comment: Try WITH (nolock)

Comment: Have tried that one. Still returning the same error

Comment: If you remove both (nolock) does it work?

Comment: Have tried all four combinations still not getting it.

Comment: Just leave out the `NOLOCK` hint.  It is probably not a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The alias needs to be before the NoLock hint.

Also, using table hints without a WITH statement is deprecated.  The parser will sometimes see `tbl (nolock)` as a function call.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbltable a WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN report.[schema].tbltablename  b WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON b.c1 = a.c1;
```

Comment: I have tried like this but not sure what error came?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that is the correct syntax of nolock.  
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.tables AS t WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id;
As to your specific query, I can't say.

Comment: I have tried with nolock on reporting and it works.  Any ideas how.

Comment: If my answer worked, please mark it as such.  As for the ideas how, are you asking how With (NoLock) works, or something else?